# Swift 2.0 : Count is unavailable access the count property on the collection

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I get error when I set a limit to the textfield to 300

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newLength = count(textField.text!.utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length
        return newLength <= 300 // Bool
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm new to swift how to edit the code to fit the new 2.0 Swift

Comment: `count(string.utf16)` --> `string.utf16.count`.

Comment: There is an error pointed to count(textField.text!.utf16) thank you Martin R

Comment: If you read *and understand* the linked-to Q&A and my previous comment then you should really be able to figure that out yourself.